# How can we get response of next loading web page

Tags: python, css, python-2.7, xpath, web-scraping

I am writing a scraper to get all the movie list available on hungama.com

I am requesting "http://www.hungama.com/all/hungama-picks-54/4470/" url to get the response.

When you go to this url, this will show 12 movies on the screen but as you sroll down the movie count gets increasing by auto reload.

I am parsing the html source page with below code

```
response.css('div.movie-block-artist.boxshadow.clearfix1>div>div>a::text').extract()
```

but I only get 12 items whereas there are more movie items. how can I get all the movies available. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While scrolling down the content of that page, If you take a good look at `xhr` tab in `network` category within `dev tools` then you can see that it produces some URLs with pagination feature attached to it like :`http://www.hungama.com/all/hungama-picks-54/3632/2/`. So, changing the line as I did below, you can get all the content from that page.

```
import requests
from scrapy import Selector

page = 1
URL = "http://www.hungama.com/all/hungama-picks-54/3632/"

while True:
    page+=1
    res = requests.get(URL)
    sel = Selector(res)
    container = sel.css(".leftbox")
    if len(container)<=0:break

    for item in container:
        title = item.css("#pajax_a::text").extract_first()
        year = item.css(".subttl::text").extract_first()
        print(title,year)

    next_page = "http://www.hungama.com/all/hungama-picks-54/3632/{}/"
    URL = next_page.format(page)
```

Btw, the URL you have provided above is not working. The one I've supplied is active now. However, you understood the logic I think.

Comment: Great.. Thank you very much. 54/4470/ is working at my end but I got the logic. :)

Comment: this will fetch all the movies available in hungama-picks (one section), but what if I want to get all the movies from http://www.hungama.com/movies/  url. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Thanks. You should create another post describing the additional requirement you expect to get fulfilled and drop here a link to that thread @ Pradeep.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an `ajax` request as a lazy load feature with url http://www.hungama.com/all/hungama-picks-54/4470/2/?ajax_call=1&_country=IN which fetches movies .
In the above url change 2 to 3 (http://www.hungama.com/all/hungama-picks-54/4470/3/?ajax_call=1&_country=IN) and so on for getting next movies detail.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood